# Finding appropriate distribution that fit to for a frequency distribution of a variable

Tags: r, distributions, density-function

I am trying to fit distribution to my dataset. For example I have data whose frequency distribution look like the following.

[image]

The following is frequency table, after divided the data in 10 bins.

```
  xvar lvar yvar
1     1   y1   25
2     2   y1   22
3     3   y1   16
4     4   y1   15
5     5   y1   10
6     6   y1    2
7     7   y1   NA
8     8   y1   NA
9     9   y1   NA
10   10   y1   NA
11    1   y2    2
12    2   y2    5
13    3   y2    8
14    4   y2   10
15    5   y2   15
16    6   y2    9
17    7   y2    6
18    8   y2    3
19    9   y2    2
20   10   y2    1
21    1   y3   NA
22    2   y3   NA
23    3   y3   NA
24    4   y3    6
25    5   y3   12
26    6   y3   14
27    7   y3   18
28    8   y3    6
29    9   y3    2
30   10   y3    1
```

`yvar` is frequency in each bin. I would like to find a corresponding distribution that best fits this trend (may be beta distribution or normal distribution?). How can I achieve this?

**Edits**:

(1) I do not need perfect fit but close fit and simple: A commonly used distribution is good enough

(2) The `xvar` is a continuous variable (like blood pressure) or discrete scale (for example 1:10 rating scale)

(3) I believe that most of it can be described by normal distribution but I have some of them skewed like `y1`. I wonder such values can be described by beta distribution, but do not know how to find appropriate value (beside just guess)?

The solution does not necessarily need to be in `R`, but following is `R` code for the above data set and plot.

```
y1 = c(25, 22,16, 15, 10,   2, NA, NA, NA, NA)
y2 = c(2, 5,8, 10, 15, 9, 6, 3, 2, 1) 
y3 = c(NA, NA,NA, 6, 12, 14, 18, 6, 2, 1)  

myd <- data.frame (xvar = 1:10, lvar = rep(c("y1", "y2", "y3"), each = 10),  yvar = c(y1, y2, y3)) 
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(myd, aes(x = xvar, y = yvar, fill = lvar, colour = lvar)) +  geom_point () + geom_line ()  + theme_bw()
```

Comment: Knowing what the data are would be useful.

Comment: @Dave do you mean what type of variable or actual data - not class frequency ?

Comment: John, could you tell us what you hope to accomplish by this fitting procedure? Is it a goal in its own right (and if so, how would you interpret the results) or is it to support some further analysis (and if so, what kind)?

Comment: @whuber what I am thinking is this will provide idea on a most fit probability density - generization on results - for example with y1 situation (say certain people with certain gene) there almost no chance of geting a value of 10, while maximum probability is 0 and some more toward 5. The situation y2 and y3 is different. I want to explain these curves in a formula, which might not be perfect fit, but explain trends

Comment: Why not just describe the curves with some summary statistics instead of formulas?  Would, for instance, saying that $y_2$ is approximately a Beta$(2,2)$ scaled by $10$ be more illuminating than saying it is symmetric around $5$ with a range of $10$?  In fact, your data are so scarce that any formula is going to appear far more accurate than it really is.  Using formulas seems to introduce a certain unnecessarily arbitrariness to the description of the data.

Comment: @whuber please note that yvar is frequency. In real dataset I have larger dataset. Here is my question, is there is any way to find such parameter parameters of Beta, instead of a guess, I am not sure if I can explain every distribution in terms of beta distribution ... thanks

Comment: No, not all your data have scaled Beta shapes (y1 clearly does not).  And therein lies a fundamental problem: there are infinitely many formulas that can be found to describe a distribution.  Without additional guidance--such as understanding what these data represent--there is no basis to recommend one particular formula over another, provided they use the same number of parameters and fit the data equally well.  There are still infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @whuber I do not need perfect fit, but I need suggestive curve to describe the distribution - please see my recent edits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agree with Dmitry and others in the above discussion. I have following general comments that might help.

We can identify 4 steps in fitting distributions:

1) Model/function choice: hypothesize families of distributions;
2) Estimate parameters;
3) Evaluate quality of fit;
4) Goodness of fit statistical tests.

The first step in fitting distributions consists in choosing the mathematical model or function to represent data in the better way. Sometimes the type of model or function can be argued by some hypothesis concerning the nature of data,often histograms and other graphical techniques can help in this step (just like you plotted), but graphics could be quite subjective, so there are methods based on analytical expressions such us the Pearson’s K criterion. Solving a particular differential equation we can obtain several families of function able to represent quite all empirical distributions. Those curves depend only by mean, variability, skewness and kurtosis.

R has several functions that might be helpful:

```
ad.test(): Anderson-Darling test for normality (nortest)
chisq.test(): chi-squared test (stats)
cut: divides the range of data vector into intervals
cvm.test(): Cramer-von Mises test for normality (nortest)
ecdf(): computes an empirical cumulative distribution function (stats)
fitdistr(): Maximum-likelihood fitting of univariate distributions (MASS)
goodfit(): fits a discrete (count data) distribution for goodness-of-fit tests (vcd)
hist(): computes a histogram of the given data values (stats)
jarque.bera.test(): Jarque-Bera test for normality (tseries)
ks.test(): Kolmogorov-Sminorv test (stats)
kurtosis(): returns value of kurtosis (fBasics)
lillie.test(): Lilliefors test for normality (nortest)
mle(): estimate parameters by the method of maximum likelihood (stats4)
pearson.test(): Pearson chi-square test for normality (nortest)
plot(): generic function for plotting of R objects (stats)
qqnorm(): produces a normal QQ plot (stats)
qqline(), qqplot(): produce a QQ plot of two datasets (stats)
sf.test(): test di Shapiro-Francia per la normalità (nortest)
shapiro.test():Shapiro-Francia test for normalità (stats)
skewness(): returns value of skewness (fBasics)
table(): builds a contingency table (stats)
```

Please read [this](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) for details on fitting distribution.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I need to say that I **do** agree with @whuber that just explaining the data with some "commonly used distribution" is probably not the best idea. A good idea would be to find the underlying model and parametrize it. And it does not need to be a distribution at all.

However, if your question is just about the distribution that looks similar to your data, I would answer **Gamma distribution**. It handles non-negativity of your data and it incorporates skewness. It has two parameters: $k$ and $\theta$, that one can estimate numerically with **maximum likelihood estimation**. However, the initial solution you can get with **method of moments**. Have a look here for further information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Parameter_estimation

Hope it will help for your immediate goals, but use it carefully :)